# Not getting Activation Email link from Code @ Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, code

I signed Up a Developer Account @ [Code.Exacttarget](https://code.exacttarget.com/), but it is not sending first time  activation link to mail Id. It says wait for minutes, but it's been 3 hrs I haven't got link.

Comment: I think we can't do anything for you here !

Comment: Are you using gmail?

Comment: @Timothy.. Yes It's a Gmail

Comment: Gmail is notoriously bad for this.  I've seen them slow delivery for several hours.  By now you should have it; if not, check your spam folder.

Comment: @Timothy.. Still I haven't got the Link

Comment: Any chance you could use a different email address?

Comment: ok..then I will check with my old Yahoo Mail Id